# How to get Line Width Of LibreOffice in python

Tags: python-2.7, gtk, pygtk, libreoffice, gedit

We will get Width of screen using gtk module like:

```
>>>import gtk
>>>window = gtk.Window()
>>>screen = window.get_screen()
>>>print gtk.gdk.screen_width()
1280
>>> screen.get_width()
1280
```

My question is that How to get max width of line in in LibreOffice using python?
Means how many character can fit in line ?

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with GTK or Python. Take your paper size in LibreOffice, subtract the left and right margin sizes, and divide what's left by your font size, keeping in mind that 1 point = 1/72 inch or 0.352778 mm.

This will only give you a rough estimate of the number of "m" characters that could fill a line. If you used a proportional font and filled the line with "i" characters, you could fit many more.